# How to have varying number of arguments with default value in function in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-visualization, user-defined-functions

I am new in R and creating a function that highlight list of countries from the data set in the plot.

**functionality issue** If country names are not passed as arguments (which can vary) then it should be able to take from default list of countries.

I understand `...` is used for `variable arguments` and then may be I can use `list(...)` but I am not able to put this together with default values.

Is there a way I can write: `country_highlight_plot(Australia, Singapore, Norway)`
and if I don't mention any country then it takes default countries.

Below is the code (using gapminder data to reproduce):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gghighlight)
library(scales)
library(gapminder)

country_highlight_plot <- function(df = gapminder, y_var = gdpPercap, 
                                   background_line_color = "grey", 
                                   countries = default_list 
                                   ){
  
  # default list of highlight countries
  default_list = c("India","Singapore","Malaysia","Norway",
                                     "Denmark","United States","United Kingdom","China")
  
  # quoting y-axis variable
  y_var = enquo(y_var)

  # Data Prep.
  df %>% 
    mutate(highlight_type = case_when(country %in% countries ~ "Yes",
                                      TRUE ~ "No")) %>%
  # Plotting  
  ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x = year, y = round(!!y_var,2), col = country), size = 1.1) +
    
    gghighlight(highlight_type == "Yes",
                unhighlighted_params = list(size = 1, colour = alpha(background_line_color, 0.4))) +

    # facet_wrap(~continent) +
    
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)
            ) +
    
    labs(title = "GDP/Cap for world countries across time",
         subtitle = "created by ViSa",
         caption = "Data Source: Gapminder",
         y = "Total Tax Revenue % of GDP" 
         )
}

country_highlight_plot()

# EDITED below line to gapminder df only
# country_highlight_plot(df=gapminder, y_var=gdpPercap, background_line_color= "pink")
```

Comment: `dots <- list(...); if (!length(dots)) dots <- default_list;`

Comment: `tax_rev` is not defined

Comment: @Peter `tax_rev` is another data frame that I believe is only used in commented code as it could work on other dataframes as well and can be changed by mentioning arguments `df = gapminder, y_var = gdpPercap`.. etc . But I will edit & update to gapminder in original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think setting a sane default value and checking for it makes sense to me.

I tend to differentiate between `NULL` and `NA`, where `NULL` means something like "use nothing or everything" and `NA` means "use a sane default".

Untested:

```r
country_highlight_plot <- function(df = gapminder, y_var = gdpPercap, 
                                   background_line_color = "grey", 
                                   countries = NA) {
  if (is.null(countries)) {
    countries <- sort(unique(df[["country"]])) # assuming 'country' is in there
  } else if (anyNA(countries)) {
    countries <- c("India", "Singapore", "Malaysia", "Norway",
                   "Denmark", "United States", "United Kingdom", "China")
    countries <- intersect(countries, unique(df[["country"]]))
  }
  # ...
}
```

This allows one to use `country_highlight_plot(..., countries=NULL)` for all countries in `df`, and `country_highlight_plot(..., countries=NA)` for your default list of countries. The `intersect` call ensures that if this function is called as part of a filtered-`gapminder` dataset, it won't look for countries that are not present. (Based on your current `%in%` usage, this might not be strictly necessary ... but if you use `countries` for anything else, it might still be useful. Defensive programming.)

Tangentially: if you're writing a function as part of a package, then I suggest you should import (mandate) the `gapminder` package, and then use a similar technique for using that dataset:

```r
country_highlight_plot <- function(df, y_var = gdpPercap, 
                                   background_line_color = "grey", 
                                   countries = NA) {
  if (missing(df)) {
    df <- get("gapminder", envir = asNamespace("gapminder"))
  }
  if (is.null(countries)) {
    countries <- sort(unique(df[["country"]])) # assuming 'country' is in there
  } else if (anyNA(countries)) {
    countries <- c("India", "Singapore", "Malaysia", "Norway",
                   "Denmark", "United States", "United Kingdom", "China")
  }
  # ...
}
```

With this, you can do

```r
# default data, your default_list
country_highlight_plot()

# default data, all countries
country_highlight_plot(countries = NULL)

# pre-defined data, all default_list countries found
dplyr::filter(gapminder, ...) %>%
  country_highlight_plot(.)

# pre-defined data, all countries found
dplyr::filter(gapminder, ...) %>%
  country_highlight_plot(., countries = NULL)

# default data, manual countries
country_highlight_plot(countries = c("a","B"))
```

Comment: thanks @r2evans for putting a detailed explanation and code. Before posting the question here I tried `country_highlight_plot(countries = c("Australia","Singapore"))` this already but I thought it is not a smart and good way of doing it. Thanks for listing all the options as well !!